# Restricting a process to a particular number of CPUs

Tags: linux, unix

Is it possible to restrict a process to use only 1 CPU, whilst not specifying a specific CPU?

I know that I can use the `taskset` command to force a process to only use a specific CPU or list of CPUs, e.g

`taskset --cpu-list 0,1 some_process`

But can I tell a process to use any CPU, but only one (or any other number)?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Why do you want to do that? Maybe there is some workaround...

Comment: I want to use multiprocessing to run a python script on a machine with many CPUs. The thing is, on this particular machine, the code behaves strangely and will use 16+ CPUs at 100% and I have no idea why. I am currently using taskset to get around this problem and manually running jobs in parallel, specifying which cores the code can use. I would like to use Python's multiprocessing.Pool object to automate this tedious process but am struggling to find a solution to the problem of assigning processes to CPUs not in use (a task which the scheduler should be taking care of).

Comment: This is already a workaround, but it isn't feasible for me to fix the underlying issue that causes this

Comment: I think that python queries the number of physical CPUs and creates thread pool of this size. And I also think that it has a function to explicitly set size of this thread pool (or maybe even to do this through env variable). So, if I were you, I would dig into this direction.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions - I will look into that!